# how to read properties from GWT host page?

Tags: gwt, properties

What's the best way to read properties from the GWT host page?

I'm trying to find a simple way to embed properties into the host page and access them from Java.

It seems like [Dictionary](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/Dictionary.html) is the recommended way to go, but it's somewhat fragile in that your dictionary **must** exist in the host page, or it errors with `MissingResourceException`. Similarly, `Dictionary.get()` will throw a resource error if the key you request does not exist.

I'm writing a library, and I'd prefer a more robust solution that won't error out if the user doesn't specify the dictionary or key. Should I just catch exceptions thrown by the Dictionary and return null?  Is there a more robust way to do this?

**EDIT**: at the moment, I'm using the following:

```
protected Dictionary dict;

public ClientConfiguration(String configName)
{
    try
    {
        dict = Dictionary.getDictionary(configName);
    } catch (MissingResourceException e)
    {
        dict = null;
    }
}

public String getString(String key)
{
    return dict == null ? null : dict.keySet().contains(key) ? dict.get(key) : null;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say, your solution is very robust already. It's absolutely ok to catch - without rethrowing -

- a *specific* Exception (MissingResourceException)
- which you expect to occur (the resource could be missing),
- and which will only occur under the circumstances you expect (it would be bad to catch a NullPointerException, because there can be many reasons for that Exception).

You could even change your getString() method a little bit:

```
public String getString(String key) {
  try {
    return dict == null ? null : dict.get(key);  

  } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

This should make the method almost twice as fast, because you save the extra call to `dict.keySet().contains(key)`, which takes approximately as long as `dict.get(key)`.